# MySQL find the top 2 busiest shipment lines with source_port and destination_port switchable

Tags: mysql

The table's structure is

```
create table t_hr_ship 
    (shipment_id int,
     shipper_id int,
     source_port varchar(20),
     destination_port varchar(20));
```

The question is: find the top 3 busiest lines and print the two ports for these busiest lines. for two shipments, one is from A to B, the other is from B to A, they'are on the same line (between same two destinations) so their shipment should be added up for that line.

I'm thinking to create a new column "line" that concatenate source_port and destination_port but don't know how to make the switched source, destination being the same line.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, specifying your MySQL version would be helpful, as the answer is going to be different depending on whether you have the newer version (that supports things like CTEs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to switch ports, if their IDs aren't in ascending order. Then group by the pair of ordered posts, order the result by `count(*)` descending and use `LIMIT` to get the top 3 only.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN s.source_port < s.destination_port
           s.source_port
         ELSE
           s.destination_port
       END a,
       CASE
         WHEN s.source_port < s.destination_port
           s.destination_port
         ELSE
           s.source_port
       END b
       FROM t_hr_ship s
       GROUP BY CASE
                  WHEN s.source_port < s.destination_port
                    s.source_port
                  ELSE
                    s.destination_port
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN s.source_port < s.destination_port
                    s.destination_port
                  ELSE
                    s.source_port
                END
       ORDER BY count(*) DESC
       LIMIT 3;
```